# Linked List not working with strtok

Tags: c, linked-list, tokenize

This is what I am intending to do:  Get the contents of a webpage, break it into pieces using strtok and storing each piece in a node of a linked list, then take each of these nodes and use strtok to break them apart further, and get the pieces of data I want out of them.  The problem I am having is that for some reason, my linked list gets reduced to one node when I start using strtok for the second time.

linked list node struct:

```
struct node {
  char* tidbit;
  char* address[35];
  char* key[51];
  struct node *next;
};
```

code that builds the linked list:

```
root = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
conductor = root;
root -> next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

conductor->tidbit = strtok(buf,"+"); // sets the tidbit variable equal to the result of strtok


// builds the linked list of items
while (conductor->tidbit!= NULL){
      conductor -> next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
      conductor = conductor-> next;
      conductor->tidbit = strtok(NULL, "+");
}
conductor->next = NULL;
```

This code works, and returns the entire list:

```
conductor = root;
while (conductor->next != NULL){
    i++;
    printf("Next %d: %s\n", i, conductor->tidbit);
    conductor = conductor ->next;
}
```

This code only returns the first item entered into the list (the extra next is because the first item on the linked list is junk data and I don't need it).

```
    conductor = root;
    conductor = conductor->next;

    while (conductor->next != NULL){
            conductor = conductor->next;
            strtok(conductor->tidbit, ">");
            strtok(NULL, ">");
            conductor->tidbit = strtok(NULL, ">");
            strncpy(conductor->key, conductor->tidbit, 51);
            conductor->key[51] = '\0';
            conductor->tidbit = strtok(NULL, ">");
            strncpy(conductor->address, conductor->tidbit + 42, 34);
            if (conductor->address[33] == '"')
                conductor->address[33] = '\0';
            else
                conductor->address[34] = '\0';
            printf("Values: key: %s address: %s\n", conductor->key, conductor->address);
            while (strtok(NULL, ">") != NULL){
            }
    }
```

Essentially this last piece of code is trying to take the string returned by the first use of strtok, and break it down into pieces delimited by ">".  The it pulls two relevant pieces of data (address and key) from the string, storing them with the node.  Then it should go to the next node and do it again until it runs out of nodes.

I have a hunch that it is strtok that is causing problems.  The sections are in variable lengths, but always a set distance from a certain character (">") which is why I need strtok.  Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: This does not address your problem directly, but if you're trying to tokenize html content have you considered http://tidy.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I don't see how that helps me in any way.  If it would let me remove all HTML tags, that would help some, but I don't see an option to do that.  Everything in HTML is well formed, the problem is literally an id value is different from item to item, so I can't just count down the string and get the value

Comment: I'd start with the simple problem that `char* address[35]` declares an array of 35 `char*`; **not** an array of 35 `char`. The rest should be blatantly obvious once you fix that. The same goes for `char *key[51];`

Comment: this is why I wish I had more experience with C, pointers....its always pointers.  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start with the simple problem that `char* address[35]` declares an array of 35 `char*`; **not** an array of 35 `char`. The rest should be blatantly obvious once you fix that. The same goes for `char *key[51];` – WhozCraig